# Compiling in release mode Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Dapper' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compilation

I have C# solution that has a UnitTest project that has a reference to Dapper.  If I change the release mode to debug the project compiles correctly.  If I change it to release it doesn't compile and I get the following error:

```
Compiling in release mode Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Dapper' could not be found
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Dapper Nuget package, but it does the same thing.

I can unload the project and recompile my solution in release mode, but I don't think I should have to do this.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the project from being built in Release mode (or whichever configuration you want) in Configuration Manager. Just unselect the checkbox for the test project for the "Release" configuration.

[image]

This way you don't need to keep unloading/reloading projects.